# What is the difference in this specific breadboard wiring?

Tags: led, power, voltage, breadboard, wiring

As an absolute layperson in electronics I just found out that an LED only lights up when connected like in figure 1 but not when connected like in figure 2. And I just don't get why?

I know an LED is a diode and current can only move through it in one direction, but that's the case in both constructions. I don't see a difference in both constructions.

So why does it obviously make a difference?

figure 1 (battery not depicted):
[image: LED is on]
figure 2 (battery not depicted):
[image: LED is off]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the second arrangement, both legs of the LED are on the same horizontal row - In breadboards, each set of 5 holes on either side of the board is shorted together.

In other words, your LED's legs are shorted together, no current will flow through it.

See this image of how a breadboard's holes are typically connected internally:

[image] ([source](http://www.technologystudent.com/elec1/bread1.htm))

The red thin lines indicate internal connections between the respective holes.

For a more detailed discussion on breadboards see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/64803/14004).

---

Specific to the Fritzing software the images in the question seem to be made in:

Note that as soon as any lead of a component is inserted into a hole in the on-screen breadboard, all the holes that are internally connected get a green indication - That shows that those holes are essentially electrically connected to the occupied hole.

Comment: Thanks Anindo, that makes perfect sense. I didn't think about the fact that the legs are shorted together.

Answer (score 0):

It's somehow clear in the second case that the LED is in parallel with a wire so the current prefers to move throgh the wire instead of the LED. In fact, the wire removes the LED.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to understand is that horizontally placed objects on a breadboard does not mean you're connecting them in series. Rows on a breadboard implies that that's the direction of current. Placing an LED horizontally on a bread board is like connecting a wire from the positive to negative legs of an LED, it will short it out. Therefore, positioning LED's vertically on a breadboard removes this short.

TL;DR : always place electrical units in vertical progressions unless you want to simulate a parallel circuit.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what value your answer added, exactly.